# Database for tracking users on a website

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, web-analytics

Consider a website getting approximately 50K unique visitors daily. Now, I want to track the user visiting the website using pixel tracking. Before starting any development, I wish to decide about the storage database that I will be using for the project.

Clearly, this will be a write intensive database with too many writes and very few searches while someone (admin) tries to see the analytics data.

So, what type of database - mysql or no sql should I use for this project ?

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt.

Thanks !

Comment: I heard that mysql is best for these write intensive applications. So, I am thinking of appending the data to some log file and then writing entire data together to database via cron jobs. Will use two files to ensure unblocking while writing to database. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: How many records do you expect per day? How many visits per user per day? How many records per single visit?

Comment: About 2 visits for a user everyday !

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided load estimates and reasonable retention policy, say 2 years of data, I believe that a regular relational database should do. MySQL supports partitioning of the tables and archival of the partitions.

The user visit data can be naturally partitioned by date. The analytic queries for that kind of data are also usually involve a date or a date range. To avoid performance problems of managing too many too small partitions, I suggest range partitioning by week.

If your data grows by, say, 2 orders of magnitude (10M records per day rather than 100K), you should seriously consider some Big Data solution. A combination of Flume/Hadoop/Hive would allow to reuse your analytic query with minimal modifications.

Answer (score 0):

From the scaling perspective the easiest thing is to write the information to files (simple log files). Then you could take [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) and process the data. First with no-cluster (Hadoop in embedded mode). Then you can add as many nodes as you like.

But critical question is also how you wanna process your data. So what is your analytical expectation. You wanna visualize your data ? How fast do you wanna get yours answers ? How fast should new data be integrated. You always have the same questions or wanna play with the data ? Wanna mix with some other data, etc...

Mysql is probably more mature in terms of analytical tools on top of it.
And its likely to be faster as long as you data size isn't too big.
With Hadoop you could use [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) and consorts to help you processing the data, but visualisation might not be as trivial.